# AngularJS the directive appears when page is loading

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the problem in FF, when page is loading, the directive appears till 2 seconds.

```js
// controller

$scope.socketconection = false;

$rootScope.$on('SocketLost', function (event, data) {
    $scope.socketconection = data; // true or false
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

```html
<div ng-cloak class="divs" ng-show="socketconection " ng-hide="!socketconection "> 
Lost connection...
</div>
```

The directive work fine. But if we reload the page, it appears until 2 second (the variable $scope.socketconection == true during couple seconds). The problem only in FF, other browsers is ok.

Comment: try ng-if , ng-show comes after dom is loaded , ng-if vl work fine. 
anyways y u r using both ng-hide & show ?

Comment: thank you. but ng-if not work as well. The problem in "$on" and "$scope.$apply();" cause the variable socketconection still == true some second when page reloading.

Comment: Don't use ng-show and ng-hide at the same time. It's useless. Have you read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak and applied what it says (i.e. add the css rule to your stylesheet)?

Comment: can't u put ` $scope.socketconection = false; ` above `$rootScope.$on`  ,
I mean ur socket lost vl take some time anyway u can't avoid that , and after that if it's false it vl hide it.

Comment: thx, but it not help.

Comment: instead of using Lost connection.. string directly, use a scope variable to define it, hence till the socketconection variable is defined ngCloak will hide it. Hope it helps